# In Linux, how do you use device_create within an existing class?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

**Note:** I'm listing this problem as it is today, I'm *not* opposed to changing the implementation (moving the creation of the class to a common area for example) if it makes things easier... I'm just not sure how to do it. **:End Note**

I've got two linux kernel modules and I'm trying to update the /sys entries for them. Searching around on google and other sources, I've seen lots of code along the lines of:

```
static dev_t MyDev;
static struct class *c1;

static int __init start_func(void)
{
    ...
    MyDev = MKDEV(nMajor, MINOR_VERSION);
    register_chrdev_region(MyDev, 1, MODULE_NAME);
    c1 = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv");
    device_create(c1, NULL, MyDev, NULL, MODULE_NAME);
    ....
```

And I've verified for my first module this code works, and that it correctly creates a:

```
/sys/class/chardrv/<MODULE_NAME>
```

entry. What I'd like to know is how do you create a device in an existing class. In other words, one of my modules created this new chardrv class, now I want my other module to be able to also register its devices under the same class.

I can't call class_create() again (in the second module), because that "chardrv" class already exists...

So I can run a check to see if /sys/class/chardrv exists, and this can help me decide if I need to call class_create() or not, that's not a problem. Lets put some pseudo code in here to clarify:

```
if ( path "/sys/class/chardrv" does not exist)
    new_class = class_create("chardrv")
else
    new_class = some how get class "chardrv" handle, or properties, or whatever
device_create(new_class, ...)
```

So as per this example, if my class already exists, and I just want to add my new device into it **from a second module** I assume I need to create a class structure and somehow populate it with the correct "chardrv class" attributes then call device_create as before, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 12):

To use the `device_create` function with the same class, just pass it a pointer to the same class.

Since you want to call `device_create` in a different module than the one in which you create the class, you'll need to export the symbol for the pointer to the class. You can use the `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro to do this.

---

For example:

**module1.c**:

```
extern struct class *c1;    /* declare as extern */
EXPORT_SYMBOL(c1);          /* use EXPORT_SYMBOL to export c1 */

static dev_t mod1_dev;
static int __init start_func(void)
{
        ...
        /* define class here */
        c1 = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv");

        /* create first device */
        device_create(c1, NULL, mod1_dev, NULL, "mod1_dev");
        ....
}
```

**module2.c**

```
extern struct class *c1;    /* declare as extern */

static dev_t mod2_dev;
static int __init start_func(void)
{
        ...
        /* c1 is defined in module 1 */

        /* create second device */
        device_create(c1, NULL, mod2_dev, NULL, "mod2_dev");
        ....
}
```

Note: You'll need to insert **module1** before **module2** since the class pointer is defined and exported in **module1**.

That should create the directories you are expecting:

- `/sys/class/chardrv/mod1_dev`
- `/sys/class/chardrv/mod2_dev`

---

By the way, if you are getting an `Invalid parameters` error when you try to load the second module, you might have to [add a `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` line to your Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360689/invalid-parameters-error-when-trying-to-insert-module-that-accesses-exported-s).

Comment: and under `/dev`

Answer (score 3):

To follow your example code, you would simply call `device_create()` again, passing the same class, eg:

```
MyDev = MKDEV(nMajor, MINOR_VERSION);
register_chrdev_region(MyDev, 1, MODULE_NAME);
c1 = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv");
device_create(c1, NULL, MyDev, NULL, MODULE_NAME);
...
device_create(c1, NULL, MyDev2, NULL, "mydev2");
```

You should definitely not need to check the path in order to determine if the class has been created. You are creating it in your code, so simply test for `c1 == NULL` or use a flag if you must.

Comment: For this simple use case, yes, that will work. What about when I have a second kernel device? When I refined my question I mentioned that a _second_ kernel module will also want to create a device into the same /sys/class/chardrv directroy. Obviously there is no need to call `class_create()` in both places. But if I do not call this method, how do I gain access to my chardrv class needed for parameter 1 of `device_create()`.
One more time: **Module 1** calls `class_create()/device_create()`. **Module 2** just wants to call `device_create()`, but requires the class reference.

Comment: So you need to add an API to retrieve the class. The simplest option is to put that in the kernel proper (not a module) and have the modules call into it.

Comment: And I'm fine with that, the implementation is flexible. However I'm still not sure how. When I call `class_create()` parameter1 is `THIS_MODULE`. Moving the creation of the class to the kernel proper, I assume `THIS_MODULE` won't work anymore. The def of the class_create function says P1 is: "_owner: pointer to the module that is to own this struct class_". This implies the owner must be a module.

Comment: I mean this politely, you are over thinking things. Just try it and see :)  - what you'll find is that the kernel header files do the right thing with `THIS_MODULE` if your code is not in a module.

Comment: I got the crash on calling the device create twice. Here is my question link - any idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085691/why-the-number-of-minor-devices-are-not-listed-here-in-this-program-in-dev

Answer (score 1):

Just create the class in the module init function of your first module, export the - global - class symbol with EXPORT_SYMBOL and use it from the other module.

Since the owner of the class is your first module, every time you add a device to that class the first module's reference counter will be increased: you cannot unload it while anyone is using it.

Answer (score -2):

Linux kernel won't allow to do that. This is the ERROR you will get.

```
**[  865.687824] kobject_add_internal failed for net with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.  
[  865.687835] Pid: 6382, comm: insmod Tainted: P        W  O 3.2.16.1JeshuLinux #1  
[  865.687840] Call Trace:  
[  865.687849]  [<c1584382>] ? printk+0x2d/0x2f  
[  865.687859]  [<c12a5438>] kobject_add_internal+0x138/0x1d0  
[  865.687869]  [<c12a5a11>] kset_register+0x21/0x50  
[  865.687879]  [<c137b63d>] __class_register+0xcd/0x1b0  
[  865.687888]  [<f8d0a0aa>] hello_init+0x4a/0x80 [sysfs_Dev]  
[  865.687897]  [<c1003035>] do_one_initcall+0x35/0x170    
[  865.687909]  [<f8d0a060>] ? enable_show+0x40/0x40 [sysfs_Dev]    
[  865.687919]  [<c10928d0>] sys_init_module+0x2c0/0x1b50    
[  865.687941]  [<c159485f>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28    
[  865.687947] Registering Class Failed**  

If you want to understand sysfs read: [mochel.pdf](www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're clear on when I'm trying to do here... at least that error doesn't make sense to my question. I want to create a class "chardrv" for example, then have one kernel module register a device into it. Say "device1". Then a second kernel module will be registering a second device into the same class "device2". So now running a list command on /sys/class/chardrv will show both devices. 

Are you saying there's no way to do that in Linux? Doesn't seem right to me...