# "Invalid parameters" error when trying to insert module that accesses exported symbol

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to share a global variable between two modules in order to understand how to use the `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro correctly, but I keep getting an `Invalid paramaters` error when I try to insert the second module.

In the first module `foo.c`:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

extern unsigned myvar;
unsigned myvar = 42;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(myvar);

static int __init foo_init(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "HELLO FROM MODULE 1");

        return 0;
}

static void __exit foo_exit(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "BYE FROM MODULE 1");
}

module_init(foo_init);
module_exit(foo_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

In the second module `bar.c`:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

extern unsigned myvar;

static int __init bar_init(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "HELLO FROM MODULE 2");

        printk(KERN_INFO "myvar: %u", myvar);

        return 0;
}

static void __exit bar_exit(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "BYE FROM MODULE 2");
}

module_init(bar_init);
module_exit(bar_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

---

I compile each module in separate directories with separate Makefiles. Then I insert each module manually:

```
# insmod foo.ko
# insmod bar.ko

Error: could not insert module bar.ko: Invalid parameters
```

If I attempt to insert `bar.ko` first, I receive the expected unknown symbol error:

```
# insmod bar.ko
Error: could not insert module bar.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

---

Here's the symbol dump:

```
# nm foo.ko | grep myvar

00000000ec933bae A __crc_myvar
0000000000001118 r __kcrctab_myvar
000000000000057c r __kstrtab_myvar
0000000000000b20 r __ksymtab_myvar
0000000000000180 D myvar
```

I'm running a **Debian** system (kernel **v3.2.21**) with a **Xenomai** patch applied:

```
# uname -r
3.2.21-xenomai-2.6.2.1-ipipe
```

Unfortunately, I don't think [`CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/KALLSYMS_ALL.html) is enabled, so I can't look in `/proc/kallsyms/` to verify that `myvar` is actually exported.

Comment: do you have a common header where you define the symbol to share?

Comment: I have `extern unsigned myvar;` in both files (I could stick it in a header file, but the net effect should be the same).

Comment: have your modules module_init() and module_exit() ? Somewhere in your code there is a EINVAL error returned?

Comment: If I comment out the variables, the module loads fine with no error; the error only occurs when the variables are uncommented. I'll code up a quick bare-bones version of each module and edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I tried your code on *Fedora 18 3.8.9-200.fc18.x86_64* and it works.
[  154.437776] HELLO FROM MODULE 1
[  162.530992] HELLO FROM MODULE 2
[  162.530994] myvar: 42

Comment: Building the two modules separately is probably what caused the need to include explicitly the `Module.symvers` from the **foo** directory in the build for the `bar` module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I decided to poke around the system to try to find the cause of the error:

```
# dmesg | tail
[11169.107152] HELLO FROM MODULE 1
[11226.101245] bar: no symbol version for myvar
[11226.101254] bar: Unknown symbol myvar (err -22)
```

Looks like the problem wasn't with exporting the *symbol*, but rather accounting for the symbol *version*.

The solution is detailed in [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L469) and is quite simple: make sure the symbol has an entry in the `Module.symvers` file.

---

For example, in my case the two modules where located in **/home/vilhelm/foo/** and **/home/vilhelm/bar/** respectively. Since I compile each module separately, each directory has its own respective `Makefile`. First I executed `make` in the **foo** directory to generate the `Module.symvers` file in that directory for the `foo` module.

```
# make
```

Next I modified the `Makefile` for the `bar` module by inserting the following line at the top of the `Makefile`:

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := /home/vilhelm/foo/Module.symvers
```

*Note that this is an absolute path!*

Finally I execute `make` in the **bar** directory and insert the module manually:

```
# make

...

# insmod /home/vilhelm/foo/foo.ko
# insmod /home/vilhelm/bar/bar.ko
```

No errors, so that's a good sign.

And now the moment of truth:

```
# dmesg | tail
[12675.200451] HELLO FROM MODULE 1
[12715.743320] HELLO FROM MODULE 2
[12715.743328] myvar: 42
```

Success! :-)