# How to create bin attribute file in /sys/class?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I want to create a binary file in `/sys/class/mydev/bitmap` to indicate the absence of my device. But it seems that there is no Linux kernel API (like `create_device_bin_file`) to create a binary file in the `class` directory. How can I get that?

I have already created a character attribute file in the `mydev` class. The code is as follows

```
static int __init module_init(void)
{
    attr.show = pciex_devshow;
    attr.store = pciex_devstore;
    attr.attr.name = "state";
    attr.attr.mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    class_create_file(pciex_class, &attr); 
}

static ssize_t pciex_devshow(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    struct dev_private *pdev;
    return snprintf(buf, PAGE_SIZE, "%c\r\n", dev_bitmap);
}
```

*dev_bitmap* is a hex format variable, how can I explore it to userspace?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after are these functions:

- `class_create`
- `class_destroy`

etc. located in [`include/linux/device.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device.h).

[Here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-14-sect-5)'s (a bit outdated - function signatures changed a little since then) tutorial how to work with this interface.

[`drivers/s390/char/tape_class.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/097f70b3c4d84ffccca15195bdfde3a37c0a7c0f/drivers/s390/char/tape_class.c) contains a good example of creating a device that communicates through this interface.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365027/2016221) looks like it's going to be helpful.

Comment: I have created a char attribute file in */sys/class/mydev/status* by calling *class_create_file*. The file *status* can expore kernel object in character, but I want it in hex or bin format. In other words, I want to create a binary format in a existing class. Does it possible?

Comment: What does prevent you from interpreting the input/output in the driver itself the way you need?